# How to read txt file with utf-8 character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'm new at this so if someone can help me.

So I'm trying to read the text from txt file that contains UTF-8 character.
So this is the code:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', file);
client.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

but does not work. It reads the signs as fractions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems odd that you're forcing the stream to be read as ISO-8859-1 when you expect UTF-8 to be coming from it

Comment: Have you tried setting character encoding? `client.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: yes, but does't work :/

Comment: Is it that the `text/xml` has an escape character? @Hana_lulu

Comment: document contains all the words in a given language

Comment: Ok. 
I found out it's not charset=ISO-8859-1' it's charset=ISO-8859-2'.

Comment: Sorry to bother you and thank you